# Multi-Node Cassandra Cluster and Inconsistent Client Read Requests

Tags: python, cassandra, distributed, cql, cassandra-2.0

I have a two node Cassandra cluster up and running and I'm executing constructed CQL queries via the python-driver API. I'm unit testing an series of models I built to abstract out most of the Cassandra API for ease of use by fellow developers. All of my tests pass when tested on a single node cluster, but after adding another node, the tests are completely inconsistent, either failing, erroring out, or passing with minimal rhyme or reason.

I am comparing the object inserted into Cassandra and the object resulting from the Cassandra query by `self.__dict__ == other.__dict__`, since I populate a class's fields based on the column values received from Cassandra.

I believe I have isolated the problem. On my seed node:

```
cqlsh:mykeyspace> select id,created_at from users;

id | created_at
----+--------------
10 | 139621386780
11 | 139621386780
 8 | 139621386780
 7 | 139621386780
 6 | 139621386780
 9 | 139621386780
12 | 139621386780

(7 rows)
```

On my second node:

```
cqlsh:mykeyspace> select id,created_at from users;

 id | created_at
----+--------------
  8 | 139621370181
  7 | 139621370181
  9 | 139621370181

(3 rows)
```

, where the first column is an integer id and the second column is a Python `datetime` object. I believe what is happening is that, when I insert a row into `users`, the row is inserted on either the first or second node, yet when I try to retrieve this object back from Cassandra, I am reading from a node different from which I just inserted, since Cassandra allows this. However, if I have `consistency_level=ALL`(which it is for my python CQL calls), shouldn't I receive the most up-to-date row data, not a row from an insertion prior to the most recent one?

---

Update

Please note that unique identifiers are purposely removed.

On the seed node:

```
$ nodetool status
Datacenter: 243
===============
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address         Load       Tokens  Owns   Host ID                               Rack
UN  IP Address 0  136.47 KB  256     100.0%  ownsuuid  58

$ nodetool gossipinfo
/IP Address 0
  HOST_ID:ownsuuid
  SCHEMA:schema
  RPC_ADDRESS:0.0.0.0
  RELEASE_VERSION:2.0.4
  STATUS:NORMAL,-1102599059356328037
  SEVERITY:0.0
  RACK:58
  LOAD:150498.0
  DC:243
  NET_VERSION:7
/IP Address 1
  SCHEMA:schema
  HOST_ID:ownsuuid
  RPC_ADDRESS:0.0.0.0
  RELEASE_VERSION:2.0.4
  STATUS:NORMAL,-1102599059356328037
  SEVERITY:0.0
  RACK:181
  LOAD:148937.0
  DC:241
  NET_VERSION:7
```

On the other non-seed node:

```
~$ nodetool status
Datacenter: 241
===============
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address          Load       Tokens  Owns   Host ID                               Rack
UN  IP Address 1  145.45 KB  256     100.0%  ownsuuid  181

$ nodetool gossipinfo
/IP Address 0
  STATUS:NORMAL,-1102599059356328037
  LOAD:139743.0
  RELEASE_VERSION:2.0.4
  RACK:58
  SCHEMA:schema
  SEVERITY:0.0
  NET_VERSION:7
  HOST_ID:ownsuuid
  RPC_ADDRESS:0.0.0.0
  DC:243
/IP Address 1
  STATUS:NORMAL,-1102599059356328037
  LOAD:164405.0
  RELEASE_VERSION:2.0.4
  RACK:181
  NET_VERSION:7
  SCHEMA:schema
  SEVERITY:0.0
  HOST_ID:ownsuuid
  RPC_ADDRESS:0.0.0.0
  DC:241
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you have more of a node gossip issue than anything else.  Are you familiar with the "nodetool" diagnostic tool that's available in your bin directory for Cassandra?

I'm running Cassandra on a 2-node cluster on Amazon EC2 servers, and I can run the following commands from the bin directory:

bash nodetool status

bash nodetool gossipinfo

You should see all of your nodes when you run these commands.  This should at least confirm that your nodes are communicating properly and distributing your data.  For my cluster, once I've confirmed that all of the nodes are communicating, I can run a select query in cqlsh from any of the nodes and get 100% consistent results.

Also, did you configure the node seeds value in your cassandra.yaml file in the "conf" folder?  Once you have your first node up and running, the second node should use the IP or name of the first node as it's seed.

Comment: It appears that nodetool status shows that the two nodes do not see each other; running it on each node only shows one ip address. However, nodetool gossipinfo shows that both nodes see each and are connecting alright, see updated post. Does seem correct? And yes, one node is set as the seed node in the cassandra.yaml for both nodes.

Comment: Wow, that's interesting.  Definitely not something I've run into in my configuration, so I can only really guess at a solution.  What are all of the ports that you have open between your 2 nodes?  I have 7000, 7199 and 9160.  I also have port 9042 open on the Cassandra nodes to allow traffic from my web server which is using the C# driver.  Maybe you have traffic closed on one of them?  I know for sure that gossiping happens on port 7000 (at least default config).

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay in replying! All the ports you listed are open on both nodes, but port 7001 is closed. As far as I know, this should be ok though.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think Port 7001 is required for anything.  This might sound silly, but maybe just confirm for sure that you're running the exact same version of Cassandra on the various nodes, and that everything else about each server is in complete alignment?  Beyond that, it sounds like you should try reaching out to someone directly at Datastax.  They seem to be pretty active here.

Comment: A coworker actually just solved this problem half an hour ago; I attempted to use a evaluation copy of Datastax as a multinode cluter, which is explicitly not intended for such use. I appreciate your help and patience with this silly mistake!